# video.js display poster image at end of video

Tags: html5-video, video.js

USING VIDEO.JS in Adobe Muse
Currently I have poster image configured to display at beginning of video,
when video has concluded I'd like the poster image to re-appear. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

In the future the *best* way to do this will be through css. I just [added an issue for it](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1675).

```
.video-js.vjs-ended .vjs-poster {
  display: block;
}
```

For now there's two ways using javascript that should work.

```
var myPlayer = videojs(myId);

myPlayer.on('ended', function(){
  this.posterImage.show();
});

// or

myPlayer.on('ended', function(){
  this.trigger('loadstart');
});
```

You'll want to test both for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks heff. Yes, I was hoping for css but couldn't locate anything in the video.js player designer.

Comment: Downvoted because it might have worked in 2014, but not working for me in 2018...

Comment: Not sure about the year, probably has to do with your version. 
 Works for me in 2020.  ‍♂️
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1938#issuecomment-77880630

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me! Video JS 6.6

```
var video_player;

$(document).ready(function()
{
    // 'videoplayer' is the ID of our <video> tag
    videojs("my-video", {}, function()
    {
        video_player = this;

        video_player.on('ended', function()
        {
            video_player.posterImage.show();
            $(this.posterImage.contentEl()).show();
            $(this.bigPlayButton.contentEl()).show();
            video_player.currentTime(0);
            video_player.controlBar.hide();
            video_player.bigPlayButton.show();
            video_player.cancelFullScreen();
        });

        video_player.on('play', function()
        {
            video_player.posterImage.hide();
            video_player.controlBar.show();
            video_player.bigPlayButton.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following as specified [here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/2661#issuecomment-150600956)

```
var player = videojs('#example_video_1', {}, function() {
    this.on('ended', function() {
    player.exitFullscreen();
    player.hasStarted(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Found quite a few different solutions for this common issue, but this is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) version **7.8.1** in 2020, following @chukwuma-nwaugha answer, I ended up with this:

```
var options = {};
var player = videojs('example_video_1', options, function onPlayerReady() {
    this.on('ended', function() {
        if (player.isFullscreen()) {
            player.exitFullscreen();
        }
        player.hasStarted(false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    /* Show poster when paused or stopped */
.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-paused .vjs-poster {
    display:none !important;
}
.video-js.vjs-default-skin.vjs-ended .vjs-poster {display:block !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using VideoJS 5.12.6. None of the solutions above worked for me. I ended up using:

myPlayer.on('ended', function(){

$('body .vjs-poster').fadeIn();

});

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @heff's reply following the downvote as CSS is working in July 2018.

After the class:

```
.vjs-has-started .vjs-poster {
  display: none;
}
```

Add the class:

```
vjs-ended .vjs-poster {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

That will restore the poster to its default visible state. The vjs-ended class must come after the vjs-has-started class unless you want to increase the class specificity.

This is working for me on two separate projects. I love the way Video.js allows me to do so much in CSS without having to struggle with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to display poster image :

```
.video-js.vjs-ended .vjs-poster {
  display: block;
}
```

Please note : you must remove `poster` **attribute**  from html video tag :

```
 <video id="my-video" style="position: unset"
                                       class="video-js vjs-theme-fantasy"
                                       controls
                                       preload="auto"
                                       poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
                                       data-setup="{}">
```

To be like that :

```
 <video id="my-video" style="position: unset"
                                           class="video-js vjs-theme-fantasy"
                                           controls
                                           preload="auto"
                                           data-setup="{}">
```